# Nodejs and Springboot connect mongodb, but editing one causing duplicate document

Tags: node.js, mongodb, spring-boot

I have an NodeJS app uses mongoose to connect mongodb and an Springboot app (use MongoRepository) to retrieve data in the same mongodb, processing it and update the document.

```
// Get Work
Work work = workRepository.findByJobNumAndFileRef(jobNum, fileRef);

// do processing
work.setUpdated_at(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());

// update
workRepository.save(work);
```

The problem is when Springboot updates the document, it create another instead of updating the original one.

```
"data": [
        {
            "_id": "5e9489ea2ea7c9fb5a6b7be6",
            "num": 1,
            "jobNum": "TG123",
            "description": "Good tesst",
            "started_at": "2020-04-04T17:00:00.000Z",
            "ended_at": "2020-04-05T17:00:00.000Z",
            "fileName": "File_Upload",
            "status": "1",
            "fileRef": "ea7lsx1dnek8ynjnom",
            "fileLocation": "../ea7lsx1dnek8ynjnom_File_Upload_1586792938917",
            "created_at": "2020-04-13T15:48:58.962Z",
            "updated_at": "2020-04-13T15:48:58.962Z",
            "__v": 0
        },
        {
            "_id": "5e948a0c590d1d5458051548",
            "jobNum": "TG123",
            "num": 1,
            "fileRef": "ea7lsx1dnek8ynjnom",
            "description": "Good tesst",
            "started_at": "2020-04-04T17:00:00.000Z",
            "ended_at": "2020-04-05T17:00:00.000Z",
            "created_at": "2020-04-13T15:48:58.962Z",
            "updated_at": "2020-04-13T15:49:32.217Z",
            "_class": "io.github.mongo.model.Work"
        }
]
```

My question is how to force Springboot update the same document which is created by Nodejs application.

Thanks

Comment: Where is the code that updates the document?

Answer (score 0):

I able to resolve my question by changing from MongoRepository to MongoTemplate

```
Criteria criteria = Criteria.where("jobNum").is(jobNum).and("fileRef").is(fileRef);

Update update = new Update();
update.addToSet("work", workData);
update.set("status", "2");
update.set("updated_at", Calendar.getInstance().getTime());

Query query = new Query();
query.addCriteria(criteria);

mongoTemplate.findAndModify(query, update, Work.class);
```

Thank you